# Does Google Earth show missing Malaysia Airlines Flight MH370 with "bullet holes"?

Tags: google, mh370

According to [this article in *International Business Times*](http://www.ibtimes.com/mh370-conspiracy-theory-plane-found-bullet-holes-rejected-australia-2663829), a man claims that the missing [Malaysia Airlines Flight MH370](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malaysia_Airlines_Flight_370) can be seen on Google Earth. The article, dated 03/19/18 3:30 AM, says

> An Australian mechanical engineer and crash investigator claimed Saturday to have found missing Malaysia Airlines Flight MH370 with "bullet holes." **Peter McMahon said Google Earth images purportedly shows the missing jetliner** in the water 10 miles south of Mauritius, an island nation in the Indian Ocean where plane debris had earlier washed up.
>
> "Four Americans were sent to Australia to oversee the findings of MH370," McMahon told Daily Star Online. "They have made sure that all information received has been hidden from the public, even our government - but why?"
>
> He added authorities "do not want it found as it's full of bullet holes, finding it will only open another inquiry."

According to this article a representative for the [Joint Agency Coordination Centre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Joint_Agency_Coordination_Centre) (an Australian government agency) told Fox News in a statement McMahon reached out to the agency in 2016 and 2017, but at no time "did the ATSB ([Australian Transport Safety Bureau](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Transport_Safety_Bureau)) suggest [McMahon's] evidence could be missing flight MH370."

So apparently the Google images do show something but not necessarily the missing flight MH370.

However I am not sure if the resolution on Google Earth is sufficient to allow user to make out bullet holes on an airplane body.

**Question:**

Does Google Earth show missing Malaysia Airlines Flight MH370 with bullet holes in it?

Comment: The ATSB has already made clear that the photo in question was taken in 2009. Can you explain why this does not answer your question?

Comment: This would have been easier to verify if we were given the GPS coordinates where the plane supposedly is

Comment: As with all claims that are based on public information, if they don't provide a link/easy way to see it yourself, you can assume it's completely made up and they're hoping you won't bother to look. Also, just looking at Google Earth now: the windows on planes are blurry, so bullet holes would definitely be too small to see.

Comment: If such a thing were found it would be in the news.  (And if Google Earth photos could image bullet holes in a submerged airplane I'd be amazed.)  (And everyone knows that MH370 never actually took off, but is concealed in a hanger at the Kuala Lumpur airport.  By the CIA.)

Comment: Cursoy look at the area where the plane supposedly is shows a lack of detail anywhere close to what has been shown in the image in articles available online.  This, combined with a lack of actual links to the location on Google Earth that would show the supposed image, makes me think this is a hoax.

Comment: 35.60 S, 92.80 E according to the video in the article in the first url. But I cannot find this in G-Maps.

Comment: Maybe Google Earth can help me find where I set my keys... I know they're around here somewhere...

Comment: @Avery Add a source and that's a perfectly good answer to the question.